# MySQL InnoDB Full text search containing email address

Tags: mysql

I have mysql community 5.6.13 on 2 mac laptops - one with os x 10.8 and another with os x 10.9.

As far as I can tell, the installations of mysql are the same but the same full text search behaves differently on each installation.

The query I have is:

```
SELECT legal_matter.* FROM legal_matter 
left join user_account 
on user_account.id = legal_matter.lawyer_id 
left join client_account 
on client_account.id = legal_matter.client_account_id 
WHERE MATCH (legal_matter.question) AGAINST ('lawyer@domain.com.au' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR user_account.username like '%lawyer@domain.com.au%' 
OR legal_matter.display_name like '%lawyer@domain.com.au%' 
OR client_account.company_name like '%lawyer@domain.com.au%'
```

On the laptop with 10.8, the query executes normally, on the laptop with 10.9, the query complains:

```
Error Code: 1064. syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end
```

TI have no idea if it has anything to do with the different OS versions, I suspect not but am at a loss as to what the issue is.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up reverting back to OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and re-installing MySQL which has resolved my problem. Can only put it down to the OS version difference.

Comment: What versions of PHP are on the two cases?

Comment: You didn't tell us anything about the client you are using to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

I had queries that used match against email which started failing when I switched to innodb since @ is used to search for words a certain distance apart in InnoDB:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE MATCH(user_email) AGAINST('test@user.com' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
ERROR 1064 (42000): syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end

SELECT username FROM users WHERE MATCH(user_email) AGAINST("test@user.com" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
ERROR 1064 (42000): syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end
mysql>
```

Try wrapping your email address like this:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE MATCH(user_email) AGAINST('"test@user.com"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

or escaped:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE MATCH(user_email) AGAINST('\"test@user.com\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: The extra escaping -- backslash in `\"` -- is needed only if the SQL is already enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol is an operator and conflicts with the BOOLEAN SEARCH... it shouldn't... its a bug.

This post, points that is more likely to be a problem of InnoDB and MyISAM...

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74042

Maybe, you had MyISAM on one machine's DB... dunno.

Comment: Lol, didn't notice this question was from years ago

Comment: The quoting above works.. I was wondering more so if there was a better way of doing it now. I'm not the original asker. I'm using innodb everywhere. I'm using 5.6.18

Comment: InnoDB full-text search does not support the use of the @ symbol in boolean full-text searches. The @ symbol is reserved for use by the @distance proximity search operator.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: The quotes work, I'm using them. I don't know about Maria, or 8.0, or even 5.7. Is this a stable way of doing it though? The documentation would suggest not but if that were the case it shouldn't work at all..

Comment: @Erubiel - Although bug 74042 may be the 'real' answer to the 'real' question about 1064, it does not address why a change in the OS caused the bug to surface.

Comment: Were you awarded a necromancer badge, for resurrecting a four year old question? Nice.

Comment: @spencer7593... nah you need a socre of 5 or more. :'( ... but talk about necromancing hahaha

Comment: @RickJames it was probably more related to the database engine (MyISAM, InnoDB)

Comment: @user3783243 ... is this a stable way of doing it? ... depends, first, what do you mean by stable? will it crash? don't think so... is it better at performance than doing the full text search in mysql in other way... don't know about it. i guess that, if you writing each query manually, there should be no problem... But if you're receiving input from some user? as you should with each input received from users... be sure to sanitize the input first.

Comment: Since you are not the original asker. i have to ask, are you using something else than MySQL? if so, what? php, python, php with laravel, django, ruby on rails? ... there should be packages to address this issue on each of those languages. Ex. for php theres: http://sphinxsearch.com/, or tntsearch, algolia service(for algolia, you have to pay...)

Comment: By this issue i mean the full text search... not the error obviously.

Comment: @Erubiel Using PHP with propel/pdo but the interaction is the same in PHPmyadmin, and mysql command line so i don't think language is relevant. By stable I mean consistent across current and future versions of mysql. It seems like I shouldn't need to rewrite all my queries, or if I must i don't want to have to redo it if I upgrade. I'm using parameterized queries with Propel but they do nothing for the `@` because they don't consider it a special character.

Comment: @user3783243 No, language has nothing to do with mysql problems... The packages i told you about are not database dependent. They usually use file collections and such, so they look in a file with a "full text search file engine based" solution. They're a way of doing full text searches outside your database, then with the results, you can consult your db in a more simple manner.

Comment: I know its not really a solution to this question in particular... more like a way of avoiding the need of this question... but comes with some effort needed.

Answer (score 1):

What is the context?  `mysql` commandline tool?  shell script?  Java?  PHP?  Other?  I *suspect* that the answer to this will lead to what changed.

Quite possibly preceding `@` by `\` will fix it.  And that fix may work in both OSs.

Do you know if the complaint is about the `@` in the `AGAINST`?  Or all of the `@`?  Try replacing the `@` in `AGAINST` with a space.

Then, since 'lawyer' and 'domain' may not be next to each other, it may be necessary to say

```
MATCH(question) AGAINST('+lawyer +domain +com +au' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND question LIKE     '%lawyer@domain.com.au%'`
```

FT gives you the performance; `LIKE` double checks that result.

Caveat:  Unless you have the min token size set to 2, `+au` will cause lead to zero hits.  One workaround is to not use the `+` on any 'word' shorter than the min token size.  (The `LIKE` covers you.)

Comment: @user3783243 - I added to my Answer.

Comment: @user3783243 - I don't have all the answers.  Suggest you experiment with various things -- quoting, `+`, word length, removal of `@`, etc.  4 binary cases => 2^4 = 16 test cases.

Answer (score -1):

**Try to use this syntax :**

```
SELECT legal_matter.* FROM legal_matter 
left join user_account 
on user_account.id = legal_matter.lawyer_id 
left join client_account 
on client_account.id = legal_matter.client_account_id 
WHERE MATCH (legal_matter.question) AGAINST ('+lawyer@domain.com.au' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR user_account.username like '%lawyer@domain.com.au%' 
OR legal_matter.display_name like '%lawyer@domain.com.au%' 
OR client_account.company_name like '%lawyer@domain.com.au%'
```

Comment: The leading + doesn't make any difference. I should also point out that the above query works in a staging and production environment both with mysql 5.6.13. Just can't work out why it doesn't work in one of my dev envs