# MySQL InnoDB Full Text Search: searching for email

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

We are using the InnoDB FTS functionality introduced in v5.6, and are having problems constructing the search to effectively find email addresses.

The @ symbol is disallowed (it will throw an error), and the '.' seems to throw things off. For example:

for: user@email.com

this yields an error because of the @ symbol:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ('+user@email.com*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

this returns no results because of the period:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ('+user* +email.com*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

this returns a result, but is not as complete as desired:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ('+user* +email*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Can anyone provide insight and suggestions for ways to improve an FTS search when using email addresses as the search term?

Comment: Check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736163/mysql-innodb-full-text-search-containing-email-address/40400206#40400206